# Drawbacks of Class A push pull audio power amplifier?

Tags: audio, bjt, power-amplifier, push-pull, class-a

I am willing to develop an Audio power Amplifier myself in a Push Pull configuration of two complementary transistors (NPN,PNP).

On the internet, it is found that most of the conventional Class AB amplifiers are designed in **Common Collector** configuration, hereby described as **CC**. The **CC** configuration is known for the amplification of the current while keeping the voltage either same or below the base input, which seems to be a major drawback to me because this is not how one should harness the full power.
**CC** is also known for driving a load of **Lower Impedance** from an input signal of **Higher Impedance**.

To harness most of the power, I have developed my own amplifier circuit in **Common Emitter** or **CE** configured as a push-pull circuit like this...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcx0fk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the circuit, the transistors are configured as **Class A** or **Common Emitter** Push Pull Amplifier. I have also played this amplifier and this is quite loud and distortion free.

This circuit is not found anywhere on the internet. As a new approach, I am quite unaware of the drawbacks of this circuit in the long run. So I thought that it would be better to discuss the long term drawbacks (if any) in this forum and why this configuration is not used in industry grade audio power amplifiers?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you actually built it for listening it, or did you simulate it? Have you simulated it and looked at the waveforrms? Wasn't your point about making this circuit to be able to get rid of the opamp stage by providing all the gain in the transistors? Because if you have the op-amp, you can just use the standard emitter follower amp configuration.

Comment: Although it sounds good to you, I suspect that it has high harmonic distortion. Do you have a way to measure the distortion?

Comment: I would consider this to be Class AB, not Class A. It's also a terrible design because it will have DC currents through the speaker. And it cannot be linear and loud at the same time due to lack of feedback.

Comment: But if you add an output series capacitor and negative feedback to the op-amp I guess it is a good citcuit

Comment: Doesn't Class AB have crossover compensation?  This looks like Class B to me.  (certainly not Class A)

Comment: @SottoVoce both transistors conduct in the quiescent state, so there is no hard "crossover"

Comment: @tobalt Yeah. With about 3 1/2 mA at their bases the collector currents will be immense. Very likely the two output BJTs aren't even close to matched and the DC quiescent speaker voltage & current with no signal will be substantial, as well. It's just +18 V minus a BE junction, then 10 k, then another BE junction to -18 V! Agreed about the lack of crossover! But it's not sane, either.

Comment: Coder, you've a long way to go. I'm not going to argue with your judgment when you write, *"I have also played this amplifier and this is quite loud and distortion free."*. But it's a terrible circuit and doesn't do justice to any speaker system you might have. When you power this thing on do you notice a sudden movement of the speaker cones to a new resting position? Or do you have some unshown DC blocking going on?

Comment: @Coder No matter how you might protest, the circuit (that I have seen several times) requires emitter resistors to avoid melt-down (plus a few more things to control the quiescent current). Emitter followers (CC) do have gains of slightly less than unity but, this isn't the major drawback you believe it to be.

Comment: @Justme have built it and played it too, in Idle mode the speaker produces a mild humming noise. When audio is applied, the humming is overpowered by the audio

Comment: @Mattman944 No I dont have anything to measure distortion. Its all based on what I have heard.

Comment: @Periblepsis a static humming sound in idle mode.

Comment: @Andyaka, if it is less than the unity then voltage at the output will be lower, and only boost in ampere should not produce much wattage?

Comment: @CoderBittu OK, what do you use as audio source then and as the power supply? Please note that your op-amp has a gain of 22 so any line-level audio will likely just clip the output and drive the the transistors into fully on/off state. If it oscillates, you might have built a D-class amp instead. Measure the signals with an oscilloscope, or maybe it is possible you built the circuit incorrectly and it does not match the schematics you drew, or the transistors may have damaged in the cirvuit already. Without proof about the circuit actually working, it is hard to believe it works at all.

Comment: @Justme Power source, a separate 5v output from transformer. Audio Source, a Chinese audio card with Bluetooth.

Comment: @CoderBittu But 5V is not what you had in the schematics. You have built a different circuit then. The NE5532 does not even work with 5V, and do you even have a negative 5V supply?

Comment: @Justme 18-0-18, 0-5 transformer. NE5532s are powered in parallel to emitter of PNP that is positive and emitter of NPN, negative. And ground that is zero. The Chinese Audio card is powered by the 0-5V coil of the transformer.

Comment: Two current sources against each other will certainly shift the middle point if they are not dc loaded. Since the repro is directly conncted it is not your case but some dc current will flow through repro if bjt´s are not matched properly. With bias like this there is no way to hold the bjt´s  without dc current through repro ( it would be mirracle).

Comment: @CoderBittu I Can go through my own process of designing something that deals with some of your ideas but produces something that will work fairly well (under 0.1% THD.) But it takes a lot of work to communicate details and I'm not encouraged that you are in a position to absorb what I may write. Which makes a huge question about whether or not the time is worth the trouble. You don't look all that serious to me, given what I see already. That's discouraging. Can you say anything that will convince me the time would be well spend?

Comment: @periblepsis Had I not been serious, I would not have thought of designing this circuit no matter how worse it is. So if your answer contains new ideas, schematics and suggestions they are most welcome.

Comment: @CoderBittu You've selected an answer. So it appears there's little need at this time. The approach I would have taken would be along [these lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UacfO.png). But that's moot, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice you have already drawn the circuit into a simulator so you can just simulate it yourself how suitable it is for any purpose. Please notice the simulator is ideal and any real-world non-idealities you must add yourself.

This circuit is not seen much because usually when transistor circuits are introduced, their properties and applications are discussed there, before going to more complex circuits like these kind of simple audio amplifiers.

One such rule of thumb is that you should never build a circuit which depends on transistor current gain, i.e. Hfe or beta, because due to manufacturing tolerances. A transistor is only guaranteed to span a specific range like 100 to 400 of gain, so even if you buy 1000 transistors, you are not going to find two transistors that have Hfe matching within given tolerance to be able to build this circuit.

To be useful, the circuit must have 0V output with 0V input, as speakers don't tolerate DC and there is no AC coupling on the output. Maybe a few millivolts is acceptable tolerance.

And because the transistors are run in open-loop, and biased with just a resistor between their bases, the output is unknown.

As the PNP and NPN transistors have identical base current, they must have identical current gain so that they have matching collector current and there will be matching voltage over both transistors so that output is 0V.

Both transistors have 80..160 range for Hfe, so average is 120, or approximately 100 as a rule of thumb.

Assuming they have 0.5V Vbe, there's 35V over the 10k resistor and both have 3.5mA of base current. Now, it means that the idle bias collector current must be 350mA. The circuit wastes 6 watts per transitor doing nothing, assuming identical current gain.

But the current gains could be 119 and 121. The other transistor would try to pass 416mA through it, but the other would try to pass 423mA. That means 7mA must be going into speaker, or 56mV into 8 ohm speaker.

Please note that I only covered how the putput will vary according to transistor beta as an example. There are also other things that should be considered how poor the output will be if one or both supply voltages are non-ideal, how the speaker impedance affects it, how the transistor Vbe non-idealities might affect it. And then the AC signal analysis.

So the circuit is not very useful as a practical circuit. The circuit is usually found in the examples of poor ciruits or as a task to analyze why some circuit is not very good.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this. It's about where I'm at except that I'd use stronger language along the way. +1

Comment: "To be useful, the circuit must have 0V output with 0V input, as speakers don't tolerate DC and there is no AC coupling on the output. Maybe a few millivolts is acceptable tolerance."- Most important part I see. This answer is quite well elaborated!

Answer (score 1):

Class A: In idle state there's DC-current = half of the peak current or more through the transistors.

Push-Pull: The nonlinearity is compensated by having 2 devices with opposite nonlinearities feeding the same load.

Both of the concepts may be fulfilled to some degree if this works without smoking and bad distortion.

The circuit is not common, because it has no control of the DC current directly through the output transistors. You may say: There is, R1 is selected for good DC idle current.

It isn't. Transistors may start a thermal runaway because there's no feedback to stabilize the DC operating point. Besides transistor individuals have different current gains. You must select a close enough NPN-PNP pair. The selection is needed also for good non-linearity compensation by the push-pull operation.

Predicting the gain of the output stage is difficult. It depends radically on the used transistors. Feedback stabilization of the gain is essential for successful high yield industrial production. A hobby circuit can work well when the total gain including the preamp stage too, is good.

Some hifi-gurus preferred the class A, no feedback-idea for  audio amplification because early transistors were so slow that the common feedback stabilized (see NOTE1) class AB amp, which worked fine with sinusoidal input 1 kHz or less could create bad distortion at 10kHz. With practical signals transient sounds (for ex drums) became muddy. Your output stage doesn't have that harm. But it can be well neutralized by the fact that you have a normal feedback stabilized stage in front of it. A modern high speed opamp should be used. In that sense your opamp is quite good. It unfortunately can be a little overloaded by the 2 parallel (for AC) transistor BE joints and that can increase the distortion. A series resistor between the opamp stage and the transistor stage could help.

NOTE1: The hifi gurus didn't blame DC operating point stabilization with feedback and even gain stabilization feedback was acceptable if it happened inside an amp stage. But gain stabilization feedback over several amp stages was seen crap because the intermediate stages could easily get saturated when the slowness of the later stages prevented fast enough output voltage changes.

Not asked, but you may have "look mama, I built this! Listen how beautifully it sounds!" -syndrome. I have had it. I was so proud of my 1st working radio receiver that I was totally deaf for its awful distortion. Others asked me to shut it down immediately. I thought the others were only dumb or evil.

Answer (score 0):

I found [a thread on dyiAudio](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/class-ab-output-stages-common-collector-vs-common-emitter.350968/) that discusses this. User ubergeeknz asks:

> In most older (pre 1980) designs that I've seen, mostly British or British based designs, the output stage is either a totem pole arrangement or in the later designs, some combination of complementary szilikai/Darlington arrangement, but where the outputs are complementary they tend to be common emitter with the collectors driving the load.
> But at some point, it seems consensus shifted towards common collector complementary output stages in class AB amps.
> Can anyone explain the rationale behind both arrangements? And why the preferred arrangement seems to have changed over at some point in the late 70s/early 80s?

User steveu answers:

> Speed/bandwidth. Power transistor are slow, or at least historically they were, and still are relatively slow. In order to make a stable amplifier with a predictable gain, you need feedback and in order for that feedback to be stable, the amplifier has to be "compensated", ie the slowest stage has to dominate the total phase lag so that the gain falls to zero dB (unity) before the total phase lag reaches 180 degrees and makes the negative feedback into positive feedback. Common collector / emitter follower stages are driven by a low impedance voltage source that provides more current at higher frequencies and therefore can drive the power transistor on and off faster than a current source and with less phase lag at any given frequency. Speed translates into less distortion because the feedback controls the output at higher frequencies, ie more closed loop gain at that frequency. Also, a follower has a local feedback and low impedance so the amplifier output buffering is faster and less dependant on the global feedback.
> Note that a Szilikai pair requires a Zobel network to stabilize the local feedback, and a follower does not.
> Note that older amplifiers used "quasi-complimentary" outputs (one side using a Szilikai pair) because power PNP transistors were rare and expensive.

Your design doesn't seem to have any feedback, which would make the final gain hard to control, especially with two different transistors.